# Как компилятор отличает "<" у шаблонов от операции сравнения?

Tags: c++

Для специализаций шаблонов, например `f<x>(1)`,
и для сравнений, например `f < x > (1)` используются одни и те же символы,
как компилятор их различает?

Answer (score 7):

Все имена должны быть объявлены перед их использованием, поэтому компилятор видит (при помощи [поиска имен](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup)), что имя это шаблон, и парсит `f<x>` как специализацию шаблона:

```
template<int> void f(int) {}

void g() {
  f<1>(2); // специализация "f", т.к. "f" была объявлена как шаблон
}
```

Первый символ `<` после имени шаблона `f` берется как начало списка параметров шаблона. Соответственно, первый не вложенный символ `>` используется как конец списка параметров шаблона, в том числе и первый символ из последовательности `>>`:

```
template<bool> constexpr int n = 0; // шаблон переменной

bool b = n<(2 > 1)>> 0;
//            ^   ^^
//            |   ||
//            |   |\__знак "меньше"
//            |   \__конец параметров шаблона
//            \__вложенный знак "меньше"
```

Для шаблонных параметров, чтобы использовать специализацию их шаблона, надо также указывать, что имя является шаблоном:

```
template<int> struct F {};

template<class X> 
void g_bad() {
    X<0> x; // Ошибка: хотя компилятор знает что "X" это тип, и "меньше" тут не применимо,
            // но в объявлении "X" не сказано что это шаблон,
            // по этому его нельзя использовать как шаблон.
}

template<template<int> class X> 
void g_OK() {
    X<0> x; // ОК, компилятор знает что X - это шаблон
}

int main() {
    g_OK<F>();
}
```

В случае имен, зависимых от шаблонных параметров, надо использовать ключевое слово `template`:

```
struct Foo {
    template<int> void f(int) {}
};

template<class X>
void g(X x) {
    x.f<0>(1); // Ошибка: "Foo::f" сравнивается с "0"
    x.template f<0>(1); // ОК: "template" говорит что "f" это шаблон.
}

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    g(foo);
}
```

Ключевое слово `template` надо использовать после `::`, `->` или `.`, чтобы указать что следующее за ним имя - это шаблон. При этом ключевое слово `template` можно использовать только если тип класса неизвестен в данный момент: класс - это шаблонный параметр, или зависит от шаблонного параметра.
Это правило также работает и в ситуациях, когда за именем не следуют шаблонные параметры (`<>`):

```
template<class T, template<int> class U = T::template M>
// Значение по умолчанию для U зависит от параметра шаблона T.
// Т.к. U - это шаблон, то после "T::" надо использовать ключевое слово "template".
struct Foo {
    U<0> u;
};

struct Bar {
  template<int> struct M {};
};
Foo<Bar> foo;
```

Подробнее об о всем этом можно почитать в главе ["14.2 Names of template specializations `[temp.names]`"](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names) стандарта.

Comment: Вообще-то об этом ясно указано в трех начальных строчках параграфе 3 раздела 14.2 Names of template specializations: "3 After name lookup (3.4) finds that a name is a template-name or that an operator-function-id or a literaloperator- id refers to a set of overloaded functions any member of which is a function template if this is followed by a <, the < is always taken as the delimiter of a template-argument-list and never as the less-than operator."

Comment: По поводу комментария выше нужны некоторые пояснения. Пожалуйста, ответьте, когда будете онлайн.